# Python class variable name vs __name__

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the variable a Python class object is assigned to and the `__name__` attribute for that class object. For example:

```
In [1]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: Foo.__name__ = 'Bar'

In [3]: Foo.__name__
Out[3]: 'Bar'

In [4]: Foo
Out[4]: __main__.Bar

In [5]: Bar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-962d3beb4fd6> in <module>()
----> 1 Bar

NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

So it seems like I have changed the `__name__` attribute of the class but I can't refer to it by that name. I know this is a bit general but could someone explain the relationship between `Foo` and `Foo.__name__`?

Comment: Although this does not answer your question directly, I suggest reading Ned Batchelders's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).  I think you will be able to answer your own question after reading it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, very helpful information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple. There is no relationship at all.

When you create a class a local variable is created with name you used, pointing at the class so you can use it.

The class also gets an attribute `__name__` that contains the name of that variable, because that's handy in certain cases, like pickling.

You can set the local variable to something else, or change the `__name__` variable, but then things like pickling won't work, so don't do that.

Comment: There are valid reasons for changing `__name__`, though, e.g. when you are creating a class decorator.

Comment: Well, if you are returning a completely different class in that decorator, yes. But then you can also construct that class with a `type()` call, which sets `__name__`. This is how I've seen it done.

Answer (score 4):

`__name__` is mere self-identification, in oder to know what type an instance of  it really is.

The other thing is the way it can be accessed with. That can vary if you re-assign it.

They both are assigned at the time you define the class.

It works the same way with functions: if you `def` them, they get assigned to the given name and they get the respective `__name__` attribute.

OTOH, if you have a `lambda` function, it gets a `__name__` attribute of `<lambda>`, because it doesn't know the name it gets assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

**Short version**

`class Foo(object): pass` creates a class and assigns it to local name `Foo`.

`Foo.__name__ = 'Bar'` assigns a new value to attribute `__name__`.  The enclosing scope is not affected.

**Long version**

The class statement creates a class and assigns to the name provided in the local scope.  When creating a class Python tells the class the name it was created with by assigning it to the class's `__name__` attribute.

Assigning to a class's attribute does not introduce a name into the local scope.  Therefore any changes to attributes (such as `__name__`) do not affect the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that in python a class is just an object like any other. It wouldn't make sense for an object to contain an attribute that was linked to a variable that refers to the object, because there could be any number of variable names referring to it. Any time you write an assignment (`Bar = Foo`) or pass the object to a function, you have a new reference. Naturally all objects must be independent of how they are referenced.

`__name__` is simply a piece of information attached to the class object, which happens to be the same as the variable name it's initially assigned to.